# Every track lasts 74:33:55 in iOS 10.1 Music app

Tags: iphone, ios, music

Every track in my Music app on iOS 10.1 displays a ridiculously long time of 74 hours 33 minutes 55 seconds, as on screenshot. Anyone know a way to fix it?

[image]

Comment: How do you get music to the phone? Seems like you could add one song you know is good and isolate this. Probably corrupt files or corrupt database that erasing content and re-syncing would fix, but you might need to triage or troubleshoot a little.

Comment: Actually, the minus sign in front makes it an even more impossible _negative_ 74 hours, 33 minutes and 55 seconds. In this universe, (at least,) there's no such thing as a negative duration.

Comment: It always has a minus symbol @IconDaemon, it is a function of iOS to show the [remaining duration](http://m.imgur.com/ZNPp7su). This is a file that has nothing wrong with it from Apple Music. Must be database corruption or file.

Comment: What's up with this "Dock Connector"?

Comment: I add music by syncing files from itunes and add to itunes usually buy buying or addin track file manually. I cannot identify the moment when this "happened" though.  "Dock connector" dispays when phone is plugged in into car - this is when I made a screenshot but does not affect the problem, and not relevant to this.